# Slow starting bitcoind

Tags: bitcoind

`bitcoind` is extremely slow to start (~5-20 minutes). I'm not talking about keeping up with the blockchain, that would be perfectly fine, I'm talking about an initial phase where it doesn't even respond to requests: any call to it returns *"error: couldn't connect to server"* (either from command line or from web).

Is it a known issue, is there a workaround?

OSX 10.6.8, bitcoind 0.7.0 (but happened with earlier versions too).

Comment: How slow are we talking? 30 seconds? 30 minutes?

Comment: @NickODell any time between 5 and 20 minutes, more or less.

Comment: I have the same issue.  Do you have FileVault trend on by chance?

Comment: @AndrewBurns nope :/

Comment: Calling for a close vote: no longer useful.

Answer (score 2):

You very probably have a massive `wallet.dat` file.

This happens with Instawallet's bitcoind, it takes an hour to start up, it spends this time loading the wallet.

If you want to make sure :

- Stop bitcoind
- Open up a Terminal, and type :
  `$ tail -f ~/Library/Application\ Support/Bitcoin/debug.log`
- Press ⌘K to clear the scrollback and window
- Start bitcoind

You should see some output when the client starts, if the problem is actually with loading the wallet the output should stop for a while on 'Loading wallet'.

Comment: mmh, seems to be stuck here `Bound to [::]:8333
Bound to 0.0.0.0:8333
Loading block index...
dbenv.open LogDir=/Users/looris/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/database ErrorFile=/Users/looris/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/db.log
`

Comment: Looks like it's loading the block DB

Comment: And what should I do about that in that case?

Comment: I'd say try to remove your DB entirely and redownload the chain see if that solves the issue, the folks on #bitcoin-dev might have some better insight here.